# I love my job, but got a new opportunity in the same field

Tags: new-job

The opportunity won't even talk to me without permission from my current employer as my current employer is a dealer of their product.  It's something I have wanted to do for years and the opportunity rarely comes along.  I don't want to risk my current role if I do not get the new one.  My boss is pretty cool and I think he would understand.  But at the same time I am not sure.  How do I make it clear that I am happy with what I am doing and the company, but I need to pursue this new opportunity?  Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if your boss is as cool as you describe him, he will surely understand that people change jobs every now and then. And if you really want to go, you will go no matter what he does; he can only make the parting faster and/or sourer. Which he wouldn't like to do if he values you.

From his perspective, if you are going to leave, it is still better if you don't stray very far in your new job. Having you in a new role at a partner company with close ties to them can be benefitial to both of you, so this can bring new opportunities to him as well (depending on your role at the new company).

So I would just tell what you told here: you are happy with your current job and could continue here, but you got a rare opportunity to fulfill your long term dream. So you hope he will understand this, and (in case you get the new job) you will be more than happy to continue cooperation in your new role, to the mutual benefit of both companies and both of you.

Comment: Yeah, he is in town today from California.  I think I am just going to talk with him over drinks at dinner tonight.  I am a bit nervous, but I think he will be ok.

Comment: @Jash - I wouldn't discuss this during drinks. Find out how things are between the two of you, but save this discussion for a formal meeting. Maybe you can set an appointment at this time, but this is too informal of an environment to drop this on him. You're there to have a good time, not drop bombs.

Answer (score 1):

What's the worst thing that could happen?

Ask yourself these questions:

- *Can I afford being unemployed for quite some time if things go south?*

  - If yes, go for it.
- *Will I regret not trying to get the new job offer?*

  - You probably will. If yes, go for it.

If you can indeed afford the worst case scenario (having to pack your bag and seek out new opportunities) then you should totally go for it.

Just ask, there's nothing wrong with asking to seek out what you really want, with something like:

*Boss, I've been very pleased working here but Dealer X has a potential job-opportunity that I'm very much interested in, I'd like to be interviewed by them and see how things go  but it's crucial that you're fine with the situation since neither I or them wish to break our current confidentiality, I'm not resigning just yet, but I need a green light from you to allow me to check out this opportunity.*

He'll either say yes or no.

- If he says he's not fine with it then you might have to reconsider your position, since obviously your well-being is less important than the company needs, but that's up to you and at least you asked.
- If he says yes then you can be happy that you now have a green light for the opportunity but from that moment you'll have to be careful about your position in the company and keep your eyes open for new opportunities even if things don't work out with Dealer X since your current boss might have to reconsider you as a suitable employee.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't discussed things properly with your potential future employer? As in, you aren't sure what the work would be, expected workhours, how much they will pay, work environment, etc? But they expect you to first tell current boss that you are considering leaving?

I'm sure everything is fine and nothing is off here... But look at the worst case scenario:

- You talk to your boss, basically admitting that you aren't happy and
  want to leave.
- The boss reacts poorly and decides you are fired.
- The "oppurtunity" learns of this, knows you are in a tough situation and
  decides they can lower the salary 20% because you are probably desperate now.

Sure, admittedly it's probably an unrealistic scenario, but it can easily be solved:

**Don't talk to your boss about a new job until you have a valid offer.**